# What things do I need to know when creating model from another controller and mass-assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment, attr-accessible

I have a model called DefaultCompany that has no controller, instead I create it through the companies_controller which calls the user.set_default_company (defined below) if they check the "default company" checkbox on the form.

Default company is a joining table of user_id and company_id.

```
class DefaultCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: company, user 
app/models/user.rb:22:in `set_default_company'
app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

I've set my user model to be able to accept nested attributes for DefaultCompany, like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :default_company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :default_company
  attr_accessible :default_company_attributes

  def set_default_company(company)
    exists = DefaultCompany.find(self.id)
    if exists
      exists.update_attributes(company: company)
    else 
      DefaultCompany.create(company: company, user: self)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the create action for the companies_controller.rb

```
def create
@company = Company.new(params[:company])

if @company.save
  if params[:default_company]
    current_user.set_default_company @company.id
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Company was successfully created."
  Role.assign_creator(@company.id, current_user.id)
  redirect_to @company
else
  redirect_to new_company_path
  end
end
```

So I'm not sure what I need to add so that mass-assignment will pass, can anyone help me figure out / explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe rails is strict about the naming in mass-assignment, so although you've whitelisted `company_id` and `user_id`, you have not whitelisted `company` and `user`.

Try changing the assignment in `set_default_company` to:

```
if exists
  exists.update_attributes(company_id: company.id)
else 
  DefaultCompany.create(company_id: company.id, user_id: self.id)
end
```

Comment: That fixed it, I did change it to the new method now reads DefaultCompany.create(company_id: company.id, user_id: self.id)

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the `attr_accessible` attributes on `Company` to `:user` and `:company` or set `:company_id` and `:user_id` in your `set_default_company` method call.

Edit:

```
exists = DefaultCompany.find(self.id)
```

This seems to be wrong according to your logic.

Comment: Yeah I actually changed that part it kept coming up with the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error so I added a rescue to that, is that what you are talking about?